# HTTP POST instead of CRUD REST paradigm

Tags: http, rest, web

I have an question: how can I use POST HTTP method to simulate CRUD paradigm. I know that I can use POST to update and create but how can I delete and retrieve a resource using POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP has DELETE and GET so you should not use POST for such actions.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616

Comment: I know, but can I use POST to retrieve and delete a resource?

Comment: If server you are using to POST to is yours then you can do whatever you want, just specify some fancy fields in POST which describe what you want and program server that id does what you tell it to do.

Answer (score 1):

To use REST you should

- POST when you want to create an item
- DELETE when you want to remove it
- PUT when you want to update it
- GET when you want to retrieve it

It doesn't make sense to `POST` to a url to `GET` data from it, that will confuse your users.

For example, with jquery with the following you create a user

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/users, 
  type: 'POST',
  data: user
})
```

...and then you could update it

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/users, 
  type: 'PUT',
  data: user
})
```

...or maybe delete it

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/users, 
  type: 'DELETE'
})
```

and try to GET it to see if it's still there

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/users
})
```

(I omitted the callbacks for simplicity)

Comment: How can I do all of them only with POST?

Comment: That is not a REST architecture